# google map api in Windows applications

Tags: c++, windows, api, dictionary

I was able to call Google Map API in my MFC project for years, but not any more(year 2018). Now my C++ based project shows a script error for Google Map API even after putting in a new API key.

How can I call the Google Map API and use it in Windows Applications based on c++ projects?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do a request to any API using c++, few examples are:

1. [C++ light wrapper](https://github.com/pedro-vicente/lib_netsockets)
2. [Qt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qhttp.html)
3. [CPR](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr).

You may also edit your question and add what kind of errors if your problem isn't about deprecation or a specific library that you're using so you can get a fix solution.